# ¿Por qué no puedo obtener los datos de un campo en un formulario? (Angular)

Tags: angular, firebase, spring-boot

Buenas tardes a todos:

Esta pregunta viene de intentar obtener los datos que estoy enviando en un formulario en **Angular**. Resulta que tengo la siguiente lógica:

```
 usuario: Usuario;
 checkoutFormGroup: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.authCheking();

    // Armado del FormGroup general.
    
    this.checkoutFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      usuario: this.usuario
    }) 
    console.log("Valor: " + this.checkoutFormGroup.get('usuario').value);
    }
```

El primer método 'authChecking' tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
authCheking() {
    this.authService.isAuth().subscribe(res => {
      const email = res.email;
      this.authService.getDataByEmail(email).subscribe(res => {
        this.usuario = res;
        console.log(res)
        
      })
    })
  }
```

Utilizo los métodos de firebase para poder saber con que email estoy logeado, posteriormente ejecuto un método que trae los datos del usuario logeado (esto viene desde el backend).

El formulario está siendo comenzado, solo tengo hasta el momento lo siguiente:

```
<form [formGroup]="checkoutFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
       <!--botón del tipo 'submit'-->
       <div class="text-center">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Realizar compra</button>
       </div>
</form>
```

Cabe aclarar que **onSubmit()** está completamente vacío.

La respuesta que obtengo cuando corro la aplicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podrán observar obtengo el json, pero no me lo asigna al campo del formulario 'usuario'. ¿Alguien me podrá orientar? muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Cuando haces:

```
this.checkoutFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  usuario: this.usuario
});
```

Lo que pasa es que estas asignando un valor inicial al formulario (El contenido de la variable `this.usuario` a *usuario*) no funciona el bind de la misma forma que cuando haces un *ngModel*, esta es la razón por la que cuando haces:

```
this.authService.getDataByEmail(email).subscribe(res => {
  this.usuario = res;
  console.log(res)
});
```

No funciona ya que no hace ningún efecto en el formulario sino solo a la variable `this.usuario`, para que el formulario tome el valor debes hacer:

```
this.authService.getDataByEmail(email).subscribe(res => {
  this.checkoutFormGroup.get('usuario').setValue(res);
  console.log("Valor: " + this.checkoutFormGroup.get('usuario').value);
});
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos ;)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ahora lo pondré en práctica!